# With Named Credentials, why should you ever use remote sites?

Tags: rest-api, namedcredentials, remote-site

With Named Credentials, do I in fact have the ability to make callouts to external systems which do not require autentication? If that is the case, why should I ever use remote sites?

[image]

Comment: Because they are less work to configure?

Comment: Hey @AdrianLarson, I'm new to named credentials, so is it just a couple of clicks that you save?  Also, what you save in those clicks, don't you gain in future proofing?

Comment: It's not any more future proof. That's not what `Named Credentials` were designed for, though you *can* use them that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remote Sites are also used for the [AJAX Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm), which lets you get around CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) security limitations in your browser. While you could use a Named Credential for this purpose (e.g. call a @RemoteAction method or webservice method), the AJAX Proxy can handle large (unlimited?) uploads and downloads, unlike the various limitations that plague the other APIs (1MB, 6MB, 12MB, 15MB are some of the limits you'll encounter using other mechanisms). So there's at least one legitimate case where you'd use a Remote Site. While I do agree that you should consider Named Credentials when possible, there are some practical times when it makes more sense to use a Remote Site and the AJAX Proxy instead.

Comment: Another typical example is when the user will provide the credentials to log in to the website/service specified in the RSS

Comment: @SebastianKessel - can you elaborate on your use case, and when the user would provide thier credentials?

Comment: The typical example is a situation where the user has his own credentials to an external system and every user will have to authenticate individually. This is very common in managed packages.